# Useful Add-Ins or Plug-Ins for native Visual Studio developer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-addins

There are plenty of different Add-Ins for Visual Studio see [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.com)
. Please share your experiences and favorites.

As motivation, here are some of my favorites:

- [Versioning Controlled Build](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/versioningcontrolledbuild.aspx) [F/O] - very handy extension for automatic build numbering
- [SlickEdit Gadgets](http://www.slickedit.com/products/slickedit-gadgets) [F] - useful editor gadget, build-in file explorer ...
- [SlickEdit Tools](http://www.slickedit.com/products/slickedit-tools) [C] - editing and versioning tools
- [Refactor! for C++](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/RefactorCPP/index.xml)  [F/C] - C++ code refactoring like C#
- [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net) [F/O] - making windows installer setups using XML
- [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net)  [F/O] - use subversion from inside of your IDE
- [Visual Leak Detector](http://vld.codeplex.com/) [F/O] - helper for debug problems
- [Parasoft C++test](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/home.jsp?product=CppTest&itemId=47) [C] - suite for code quality assurance
- [Parasoft Insure++](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/home.jsp?product=Insure&itemId=63) [C] - runtime memory analysis
- [RockScroll](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx) [F] - helper for scrolling in long files
- [Axialis IconWorkshop](http://www.axialis.com/download/iwlite.html) [F/C] - icon and bitmap editor
- [PowerCommands](http://www.visualstudiogallery.com/ExtensionDetails.aspx?ExtensionId=df3f0c30-3d37-4e06-9ef8-3bff3508be31) [F] - adds some useful commands onto the context menu
- [IncrediBuild](http://www.xoreax.com/main.htm) [C] - speedup your build process
- [Workspace Whiz](http://workspacewhiz.com) [F/C] - many useful add-ins
- [Consolas Font Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=22e69ae4-7e40-4807-8a86-b3d36fab68d3&displaylang=en) [F] - very nice font for programming
- [Intel Parallel Studio](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-parallel-studio-home) [C] - Intel optimized C/C++ compiler analyser and debug-helper
- [Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 IDE Enhancements](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=cd7c6e48-e41b-48e3-881e-a0e6e97f9534&DisplayLang=en) [F] - only for VS2005, Outliner / C++ Snippets /...
- [codekana](http://www.codekana.com) [F] - very similar with Visual Assist
- [Visual Local History](http://www.codeplex.com/VLH2005) [F] - local file history à la Eclipse
- [ResOrg](http://www.riverblade.co.uk/products/resorg/index.html) [F] - Manage and Renumber Resource Symbol IDs
- [PVS-Studio](http://pvs-studio.viva64.com) [C] - static code analyzer, especially 64-bit code analysis (Viva64)
- [ASP.NET/HTML Spell Checker for VS](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/11/29/spell-checker-update-2-2-full-support-for-vs-2008-sp1-simpler-setup-and-a-few-bug-fixes.aspx) [F] - spell checker.

**Tools**

- [Ranorex](http://www.ranorex.com) [C] - GUI testing and automation framework
- [OneTime](http://www.axosoft.com) [F/C] - Software project management
- [CppCheck](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppcheck) [F/O] - Static analysis of C/C++ code
- [Online GUID Generator](http://www.guidgenerator.com) [F] - in case you need a GUID
- [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org) [F] - file / directory comparing
- [codepad](http://codepad.org) [F] - online compiler
- [Cilk++](http://www.cilk.com) [F/C] - optimize your application for multicore processors
- [Microsoft Application Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c4a25ab9-649d-4a1b-b4a7-c9d8b095df18&DisplayLang=en#filelist) [F] - runtime verification tool for native code
- [SourceMonitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html) [F] - simple code metrics measurement tool
- [WinUnit](http://winunit.codeplex.com/) [F] - nice unit testing for native (C/C++) code on Windows
- [Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy/) [F] - simple code profiling tool
- [Visual Sidekick](http://www.visualsidekick.com/Syntaxia/HomePage.php) [P] - effective but cheap incremental search over symbols and files
- [CodeAnalyst](http://developer.amd.com/cpu/codeanalyst/Pages/default.aspx) [F] - code profiling tool from AMD (also partially works on Intel)
- [Sisulizer](http://www.sisulizer.com/) [C] - Visual Software Localization Tool
- [Innovasys HelpStudio Lite](http://www.innovasys.com/products/hslite/overview.aspx?cpid=vssdk) [F/C] - create Microsoft Help 2.x help systems.

**For coffe break**

- [Powder Toy](http://powder.unaligned.org) [F] - build thrilling simulations yourself
- [OE-CAKE](http://www.octaveengine.com/en_casual/oecake) [F/C] - build fluid simulations yourself.

**Your suggestions:**

- [ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com) [C] - VI emulation
- [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com) [C] - "La Crème de la Crème"
- [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn) [C] - very nice SVN provider
- [Visual Lint](http://www.riverblade.co.uk) [C] - advanced static code analysis
- [VSFileExplorer](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/vsfileexplorer) [F] - self explaining
- [P/Invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net) [F] - helps to find native code signatures for managed code.

---

[F] - freeware
[O] - open source
[C] - commercial.

Comment: BTW, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106340/what-is-your-favorite-visual-studio-add-insetting) post is essentially the same thing.

Comment: he he was going to say the same thing myself...

Comment: just nitpicking typo: for Visual Assist it's "La Crème de la Crème" :-)

nice list BTW.

Comment: WiX was not included in Visual Studio 2010, I corrected that.

Comment: *Online GUID Generator [F] - in case you need a GUID* Or don't know how to use your IDE? http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-fNr9nipDNbI/T8g_3hn51vI/AAAAAAAAAc4/l44htafIY00/s1600/GUID.jpg

Answer (score 42):

I'm amazed that [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) has not been mentioned yet!

Comment: Visual Studio is not the same without this plug-in. I cannot live without it!

Comment: Agreed 100%. No Life without Visual Assist Whole Tomato...

Answer (score 7):

[ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com/) is my personal favorite.  Emulates VI right inside of VS.  :^)

Answer (score 5):

Is nobody using [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html)? - Shame on you! ;-)

Seriously, you don't know what you're missing (I do, because I've yet to convince my boss to buy it, and my evaluation period has expired)

The addition of this tool to visual studio almost brings it up to the level of [IntelliJ Idea for Java](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html)

Comment: ReSharper is offtopic here :) Useful Add-Ins or Plug-Ins for __native__ Visual Studio developer.

Comment: Not quite sure how Resharper doesn't qualify as an add-in or plug-in - or how using any such program can maintain the _native_ nature of Visual Studio ? Each to his own, I suppose.

Comment: Native in the context of this question appears to mean un-managed.  As in C/C++ and not C#.

Comment: ReSharper will have C++ support soon, but for what it's worth it's not totally useless with C++ projects. You can still `CTRL+T` and use its solution navigation capabilities.

Comment: @PavelMinaev ReSharper have support C++, [see here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/cpp.html)

Answer (score 3):

RockScroll is awesome, but there is something more powerful: [MetalScroll](http://code.google.com/p/metalscroll/) :)

btw... I also recommend this patch: http://code.google.com/p/metalscroll/issues/detail?id=9

Comment: Thanks! I replaced RockScroll with MetalScroll after reading this answer. A number of features improvements and better stability. I would recommend anyone to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

[VSFileExplorer](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/vsfileexplorer/) is a nice file explorer for VS. It's also very helpful when used together with subversion/tortoiseSVN, since it displays the tortoise overlay icons within VS.

and of course

[GhostDoc](http://www.roland-weigelt.de/ghostdoc/) for generation of XML doc comments for methods, properties, classes, ...

Answer (score 2):

- Visual assist X
- P/Invoke
- Refactor!

Answer (score 1):

assist is very useful, visual lint is good but boring.

Answer (score 1):

A minor one by me: [Linkify](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/Linkify.aspx) that simplifies links in comments to dev wiki, msdn, bug tracker etc.

Answer (score 0):

My two pennies worth: [TabStudio](http://www.tabsstudio.com/) and [RockScroll](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx).

Tab Studio is uber-awesome when working on WPF / Silverlight apps, trying to keep track of any number of code behind, view-model and xaml files.

Rock scroll is great for larger files and quickly finding references.