# What AddOns/AddIns are available for VS 2005 IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2005, add-in

I want a complete list of AddOns/AddIns available for VS 2005 IDE

Comment: Why? There could be thousands and thousands to get a "complete list."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio add-on gallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389705/visual-studio-add-on-gallery)

Answer (score 1):

Dupe:

[Useful Add-Ins or Plug-Ins for native Visual Studio developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379453/useful-add-ins-or-plug-ins-for-native-visual-studio-developer)

[Recommended add-ons/plugins for Microsoft Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767/do-you-have-any-recommended-add-onsplugins-for-microsoft-visual-studio)

[What Visual Studio add-ins do you use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784/what-visual-studio-add-ins-do-you-use)

[Visual Studio add-on gallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389705/visual-studio-add-on-gallery)

And many others...there's no definitive list.